# Obtaining all constraint violations for field using javax.validation.Validator

Tags: bean-validation

I have the following field:

```
@Size(min=1, max=64)
@NotNull(message="may not be blank")
private String name;
```

I'd like to coax validation to give me all constraint violations.  For example, when setting name to 'null', I'd like to receive: "may not be blank" AND "size must be between 1 and 64"

Currently I only receive: "may not be blank"

Any tips on how to configure the validation engine?  Here's my current configuration via Spring:

```
<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationPropertyMap">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="hibernate.validator.fail_fast" value="false" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bean Validation specification recommends to treat `null` as valid value; all built-in constraints such as `@Size` follow that recommendation (except `@NotNull` of course), therefore a `null` value will only create a violation for the `@NotNull` constraint in your case.

The only solution for this requirement I see is to disable the default validators for the built-in constraints via an [XML constraint mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e2308) and register custom implementations which handle `null` as invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though over-riding the built-in constraints seems like more work than the extra validation message is worth.